# Beveller Not ... well, Bevelling

Tags: bevel

I'm introducing myself to the Blender community via a problem. I use Ctrl+B to use the beveling tool on a cylinder (LEGO head), and everything looks like it's working, only no bevel. Just straight orange lines across the shape. I made sure to apply scale, so I don't know what the problem is.

[image]

Any help would be extremely appreciated! Maybe a LEGO statue in your honor. :-)

Comment: I have no idea why it is not beveling as it should be but one thing I noticed is that if you look at the top of your screen where it gives the vertex count, edge and face count, it is indicating that you have 256 vertices selected.This is twice as many as it should be. You have 4 edge loops selected 4 x 32 = 128. I would suggest that you delete the cylynder that you are using for a head and add a new one, then try bevel tool again.

Comment: Are there any top and bottom faces in your cylinder? Are there any duplicate vertex or geometry there? Is your *Bevel Factor* set to any value other than 0.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the edges at the end of your cylinder when you add the bevel.

It looks like you have selected an edge loop that is offset from the end, which just adds extra edge loops along the cylinder.

[image: bevel adding edge loops]

The bevel tool needs a corner to do add a bevel. Use the <kbd>[image: MW] mouse wheel</kbd> to add extra cuts to get the rounded bevel.

[image: a good bevel]